# When saying 'He pointed out the bank of England' which of the following statements is correct?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> He pointed out the bank of England...
>   ... he said that London's City was a village in its way....

Do the extracts above mean:

1. one time in the past he pointed out and he said...
2. more than one time or every time they were out, he kept pointed and said...

NB As we know simple past does not always refer to completed action in the past. I want to translate it to Farsi and I do not know which one is correct.

Here is the passage:

> Among these adult people Cecilia was lonely, and friendless, too, in Buckingham Street. At weekends her father did his best, making an effort to be interesting on their strolls about the deserted city streets - the Strand and Ludgate Hill, Cheapside and Poultry, Threadneedle, Cornhill. He pointed out the bank of England, the Stock Exchange: he said that London's City was a village in its way. Sometimes, as a change, he booked two rooms at a small hotel in Suffolk, usually at Hintlesham or Orford

Answer (score 2):

It's ambiguous, but I would probably assume that he did so only once. If he did so regularly, I would expect *he used to point out the Bank of England*.

Comment: or, `he would point out the Bank of England`.

Answer (score -2):

On the several weekends they shared, he repeatedly pointed things out. The list indicates what he pointed out. Did he repeat himself?

I had a father who repeated himself. I am a father who repeats himself. He *surely* repeated himself. Does the grammar make it absolutely unambiguous as to whether he said *Bank of England* or *London's City is a village* more than once?

No. But I know he did.

But what does it matter?

Comment: It matters because some languages (such as, presumably, Farsi) differentiate more distinctly in conjugation between events that occurred habitually in the past and events that occurred once in the past.

Comment: @KeithB This is clearly a discussion about habitual activities, but the repetition of a particular site is not unambiguous.